# How do I convert Epoch time to Date in Open Refine?

Tags: date, epoch, openrefine

I don't care which language I use (as long as it's one of the three available in Open Refine), but I need to convert a timestamp returned from an API from epoch time to a regular date (see Expression box in the screenshot below). Not too picky about the output date format, just that it retains the date down to the second. Thanks!

Can use: GREL, Jython, or Clojure.

[image: Converting Epoch time to date in Open Refine]

Comment: Pick *one* environment/language/binding (or leave it unspecified in this case) and avoid tag-spam.

Comment: @user2864740 I chose to leave all of the languages as options because I imagine in this case it's more important to just get the number converted as opposed to worrying about which language you use to make that happen. I'm trying to reach out to the entire universe of people who know all three languages as opposed to just one. Thought this question (and answer) might be useful to anyone using Open Refine. Would you say this is not an appropriate approach?

Comment: @Chiron What have I tried? A lot of googling and no answers. I googled all three languages.

Comment: In Clojure you'd do `(java.util.Date. (* 1000 1405742701))`

Comment: @DiegoBasch Hmm... I'm having a hard time translating that to something usable. I tried a few things, e.g. (java.util.Date. (* 1000 value)). Nothing is happening. I don't know Clojure so I'm not sure how to troubleshoot that.

Answer (score 1):

If you have to stick to GREL you can use the following one-liner:

```
inc(toDate("01/01/1970 00:00:00","dd/MM/YYYY H:m:s"),value.toNumber(),"seconds").toString('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')
```

### Breaking it down:

`inc(date d, number value, string unit)` as defined in the [GREL documentation](https://github.com/OpenRefine/OpenRefine/wiki/GREL-Date-Functions) : Returns a date changed by the given amount in the given unit of time. Unit defaults to 'hour'

`toDate(o, string format)` : Returns `o` converted to a date object. (more complex uses of `toDate()` are shown in the [GREL documentation](https://github.com/OpenRefine/OpenRefine/wiki/GREL-Date-Functions))

1. We use the string `"01/01/1970 00:00:00"` as input for `toDate()` to get the start of the UNIX Epoch (January 1st 1970 midnight).
2. We pass the newly created date object into `inc()` and as a second parameter the result of `value.toNumber()` (assuming value is a string representation of the number of seconds since the start of the Unix Epoch), as a 3rd parameter, the string `"seconds"` which tells `inc()` the unit of the 2nd parameter.
3. We finally convert the resulting date object into a string  using the format: `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`

### Test Data

Following is a result of using the function described above to turn a series of timestamps grabbed from the [Timestamp Generator](http://www.timestampgenerator.com/) into string dates.

```
| Name      | Value      | Date String         | 
|-----------|------------|---------------------| 
| Timestamp | 1491998962 | 2017-04-09 12:09:22 | 
| +1 Hour   | 1492002562 | 2017-04-09 13:09:22 | 
| +1 Day    | 1492085362 | 2017-04-10 12:09:22 | 
| +1 Week   | 1492603762 | 2017-04-16 12:09:22 | 
| +1 Month  | 1494590962 | 2017-05-09 12:09:22 | 
| +1 Year   | 1523534962 | 2018-04-09 12:09:22 |
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I do not think you can do it with a GREL statement like this or somesuch, but I might be pleasantly surprised by someone else that can make it work somehow:

```
value.toDate().toString("dd/MM/yyy")
```

So in the meantime, use this Jython / Python Code:

```
import time;

# This is a comment.
# We change 'value' to an integer, since time needs to work with numbers.
# If we needed to, we could also * 1000 if we had a Unix Epoch Time in seconds, instead of milliseconds.

# We also have no idea what the local time zone is for this, which could affect the date.  But we digress...

epochlong = int(float(value));

datetimestamp = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', time.localtime(epochlong));

return datetimestamp
```